# What do Trollocs do when not the Dark Ones bidding?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time

Is the everyday life of a Trolloc mentioned later in the series,(just started book 3).

How do they eat? What do they eat?

These kind of 'economic' issues bug me in S&SF sometimes...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Trollocs are carnivores, and eat pretty much whatever meat they can get, but they prefer human flesh.  After the Breaking, they staged raids from the Blight to Borderlands areas to seek captives for food, and during the War of Power human breeding camps were set up to provide food for the trolloc forces.

Some victims of raids are also given to [Forgers](http://wot.wikia.com/wiki/Forger) to be sacrificed for the creation of the blades wielded by Myrddraal

Not much is known about their everyday life aside from the fact that they are tribal, broken into 12 primary "bands" that only work together when forced (usually by myrddraal).

The [twelve principal bands](http://wot.wikia.com/wiki/Trolloc) are:

- Ahf'frait - badge is a silver whirlwind
- Al'ghol - badge is a hooked axe
- Bhan'sheen - badge is a dagger-pierced skull
- Dha'vol - badge is a horned skull
- Dhai'mon - badge is an iron fist
- Dhjin'nen - badge is a skull cloven by a scythe-curved sword
- Ghar'gheal - badge is piled human skulls
- Ghob'hlin - badge is a flaming goat skull
- Gho'hlem
- Ghraem'lan - badge is forked lightning
- Ko'bal - badge is a blood-red enameled trident
- Kno'mon - badge is a red, blood-stained fist

Comment: great info! - I've only just seen the puns! doh!

Comment: Just think that border raiding carnivores would pretty soon exhaust their supply on food.

Comment: @Adrian I think its safe to assume they also kill and eat whatever they can find in the Blight (that doesn't kill them first).

Comment: And, in a pinch, probably each other.

Comment: @technophile I can't remember where, but I think this is explicitly confirmed somewhere in one of the earlier books.

Comment: @technophile We do see a lot of Trollocs eating (dead) Trollocs toward the end.